# Index all *except* one item in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing

Is there a simple way to index all elements of a list (or array, or whatever) **except** for a particular index?  E.g.,

- `mylist[3]` will return the item in position 3
- `milist[~3]` will return the whole list except for 3

Comment: I think it's worth going down to [@VladBezden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150767/7009806), which seems to be the most complete one to me.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

For a **list**, you could use a list comp.  For example, to make `b` a copy of `a` without the 3rd element:

```
a = range(10)[::-1]                       # [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
b = [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i!=3]   # [9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

This is very general, and can be used with all iterables, including numpy arrays.  If you replace `[]` with `()`, `b` will be an iterator instead of a list.

Or you could do this in-place with `pop`:

```
a = range(10)[::-1]     # a = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
a.pop(3)                # a = [9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

In **numpy** you could do this with a boolean indexing:

```
a = np.arange(9, -1, -1)     # a = array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
b = a[np.arange(len(a))!=3]  # b = array([9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

which will, in general, be much faster than the list comprehension listed above.

Answer (score 111):

The simplest way I found was:

```
mylist[:x] + mylist[x+1:]
```

that will produce your `mylist` without the element at index `x`.

#### Example

```
mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = 3
mylist[:x] + mylist[x+1:]
```

**Result produced**

```
mylist = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I found this actually remove the item x+1, still useful though, thanks

Comment: @JackTC it shouldn't

Comment: Python seems to be somehow outdated in case of basic operations

Comment: `exc = lambda s, i: s[:i] + s[i+1:]`
`exc(mylist, 3)`  

[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]

Comment: if `x==5`, it will **not** raise an IndexError. In Python, list slicing out of bounds does not result in an error, because when the start/end indices of the slice are greater than the length of the list, then they are simply reduced to the length of the list. Source: [Python Docs note 4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)

Comment: This is 7x faster than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 60):

```
>>> l = range(1,10)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l[:2] 
[1, 2]
>>> l[3:]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l[:2] + l[3:]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

See also

[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Good answer for a list. You could use it for arrays too but you'd need to use `numpy.concatenate`.

Comment: It doesn't work for range in python3

Answer (score 33):

If you are using numpy, the closest, I can think of is using a mask

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(1,10)
>>> mask = np.ones(arr.shape,dtype=bool)
>>> mask[5]=0
>>> arr[mask]
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```

Something similar can be achieved using `itertools` without `numpy`

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> arr = range(1,10)
>>> mask = [1]*len(arr)
>>> mask[5]=0
>>> list(compress(arr,mask))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I might use something like `np.arange(len(arr)) != 3` as the mask, because then it can be inlined, e.g. `arr[~(np.arange(len(arr)) == 3)]` or whatever.

Comment: @DSM: Please post this as an answer :-). Any case, I am not quite conversant with Numpy.

Comment: +1 for masking an array, in the case of a list I would go with slice and concatenate over using compress.

Answer (score 19):

Use `np.delete` ! It does not actually delete anything inplace

In your example, "mylist[~3]" would be written like that: `mylist.delete(3)`

A more complex example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,4],[5,7],[3,1]])                                       
 
# a: array([[1, 4],
#           [5, 7],
#           [3, 1]])

ind = np.array([0,1])                                                   

# ind: array([0, 1])

# a[ind]: array([[1, 4],
#                [5, 7]])

all_except_index = np.delete(a, ind, axis=0)                                              
# all_except_index: array([[3, 1]])

# a: (still the same): array([[1, 4],
#                             [5, 7],
#                             [3, 1]])
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to provide a functional (immutable) way of doing it.

1. The standard and easy way of doing it is to use slicing:

   ```
   index_to_remove = 3
   data = [*range(5)]
   new_data = data[:index_to_remove] + data[index_to_remove + 1:]

   print(f"data: {data}, new_data: {new_data}")
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], new_data: [0, 1, 2, 4]
   ```
2. Use list comprehension:

   ```
   data = [*range(5)]
   new_data = [v for i, v in enumerate(data) if i != index_to_remove]

   print(f"data: {data}, new_data: {new_data}")
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], new_data: [0, 1, 2, 4]
   ```
3. Use filter function:

   ```
   index_to_remove = 3
   data = [*range(5)]
   new_data = [*filter(lambda i: i != index_to_remove, data)]
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], new_data: [0, 1, 2, 4]
   ```
4. Using masking. Masking is provided by [itertools.compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) function in the standard library:

   ```
   from itertools import compress

   index_to_remove = 3
   data = [*range(5)]
   mask = [1] * len(data)
   mask[index_to_remove] = 0
   new_data = [*compress(data, mask)]

   print(f"data: {data}, mask: {mask}, new_data: {new_data}")
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], mask: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], new_data: [0, 1, 2, 4]
   ```
5. Use [itertools.filterfalse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) function from Python standard library

   ```
   from itertools import filterfalse

   index_to_remove = 3
   data = [*range(5)]
   new_data = [*filterfalse(lambda i: i == index_to_remove, data)]

   print(f"data: {data}, new_data: {new_data}")
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], new_data: [0, 1, 2, 4]
   ```

Comment: Ah! filterfalse is a great solution here (and my vote for the best non-numpy solution). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For 1D `numpy`, `np.concatenate` is faster than `np.arange` method.

Benchmark:

```py
x = np.arange(1000) * 2
i = 3

%timeit np.concatenate((x[:i],x[i+1:]))
%timeit x[np.arange(len(x))!=i]

# 9.21 µs ± 467 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 32.8 µs ± 7.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idxs = list(range(len(array))).remove(idx)
array[idxs]
```

This should work, it removes the not needed index and then slices the array

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the index beforehand here is a function that will work

```
def reverse_index(l, index):
    try:
        l.pop(index)
        return l
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if variable is list of lists, some approaches would fail.
For example:

```
v1 = [[range(3)] for x in range(4)]
v2 = v1[:3]+v1[4:] # this fails
v2
```

For the general case, use

```
removed_index = 1
v1 = [[range(3)] for x in range(4)]
v2 = [x for i,x in enumerate(v1) if x!=removed_index]
v2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut out the last or the first do this:

```py
list = ["This", "is", "a", "list"]
listnolast = list[:-1]
listnofirst = list[1:]
```

If you change 1 to 2 the first 2 characters will be removed not the second.
Hope this still helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=[1,3,5,7,9]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arsum = arr[:i] + arr[i + 1:]
```