# Retrieving all but one elements in a list of lists (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do a 10-fold cross validation for a sentiment classifier. For this purpose, I have created a list of 10 lists, where each list corresponds to one of the folds and contains movie reviews.

I am trying to create a loop, where for every iteration I use 9 folds for training the classifier and one fold for testing it. However, I am facing difficulties with subsetting the list of lists to create two variables (one for the fold, and one for the 9 remaining folds), which I can pass through my train and test functions.

I created this example as a more-readable version of my code:

```
list1 = [{"ID":1, "sentiment":"positive", "content": "further lists within lists"}]
list2 = [{"ID":2, "sentiment":"positive", "content": "further lists within lists"}]
list3 = [{"ID":3, "sentiment":"positive", "content": "further lists within lists"}]
list4 = [{"ID":4, "sentiment":"positive", "content": "further lists within lists"}]
list5 = [{"ID":5, "sentiment":"positive", "content": "further lists within lists"}]

list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]

for list_ in list_of_lists:
  remaining_lists = list_of_lists[~list_]
  train_classifier(remaining_lists)
  test_classifier(list_)
```

The error I get is "bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'".
I have seen the answers to a related question at [Index all *except* one item in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286657/index-all-except-one-item-in-python), but I could not implement the solutions suggested in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the indices of the outer list (`list_of_lists`) and exclude the list at that index on each iteration of the loop.

Example:

```py
for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    remaining_lists = list_of_lists[0:i] + list_of_lists[i+1:]
    train_classifier(remaining_lists)
    excluded_list = list_of_lists[i]
    test_classifier(excluded_list)
```

Resulting IDs of lists per iteration:

```
Remaining    | Excluded
-------------+---------
[2, 3, 4, 5] | 1
[1, 3, 4, 5] | 2
[1, 2, 4, 5] | 3
[1, 2, 3, 5] | 4
[1, 2, 3, 4] | 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

1. **What you are doing:**

```
    list_of_list = [ [10], [20] , [30] , [40] ]

    for sub_lst in list_of_list:
        print( list_of_list[ ~sub_lst ] )
```

2. **What you are getting:**
   `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'`
3. **Reason:**
   Because you can give only an index in `list_of_list[ index_here ]` index might be simple in range `0 to length-1` or index can be negated using `~` but you **cannot** give an **instance of a list** in index's place while iterating over `list_of_list` you get an *instance of each list (`sub_lst`) inside `list_of_list[ index_here ]` one after another*

```
# check type as follow
>>> type(list_of_list[0]) 
    <class 'list'>
```

4. **How will you achieve the desired outcome:**

```
list_of_list = [ [10], [20] , [30] , [40] ]
for index,sub_lst in enumerate(list_of_list):
    remaining_lst = list_of_list[:index] + list_of_list[index+1:]

    print("Sub list: ", sub_lst)
    print("Remaining list: ", remaining_lst)
    print()
```

5. **Results:**

```
Sub list:  [10]
Remaining list:  [[20], [30], [40]]

Sub list:  [20]
Remaining list:  [[10], [30], [40]]

Sub list:  [30]
Remaining list:  [[10], [20], [40]]

Sub list:  [40]
Remaining list:  [[10], [20], [30]]
```

**I hope it helps !!!**

Answer (score 1):

you can do this as follows:

```
for list_ in list_of_lists:
  newlist=list_of_lists.copy()
  newlist.remove(list_)
  newlist.remove()
  train_classifier(newlist)
  test_classifier(list_)
```