Optimizing Omission/Comission Errors Computation from Scikit-Learn Confusion Matrix in Python
I need to compute the omission/commission errors from a Confusion Matrix generated using the Scikit-Learn package in Python with the function sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix (source of the formulas: Cal Poly Humboldt)

Omission Error = Incorrectly classified references of i-th class / Total # of i-th class


Commission Error =  Incorrectly classified sites of i-th class / Total # of i-th class

While I have a solution in place, I'm wondering if there's a more efficient or optimized method available.
Current approach
Here's the code snippet of my current approach to compute the omission error:
import numpy as np

cm_rmi = np.array([
    [21, 5, 7],
    [6, 31, 2],
    [0, 1, 22]
])

def omission_error(cm):
    """Divide the omission errors by the row totals."""
    # Number of classes
    ncls = cm.shape[0]
    # Array to store omission errors by class
    omerrs = []

    for cls in range(0, ncls):
        # Get truth values of i-th class
        cls_truth = cm[cls,]
        # Retrieve all except the current class' value
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19286855/23551600
        cls_omerrs = cls_truth[np.arange(len(cls_truth)) != cls]

        # Compute omission error of the current class
        omerrs.append(cls_omerrs.sum() / cls_truth.sum())

    return omerrs

The result is the omission errors of each class:
# [0.36363636363636365, 0.20512820512820512, 0.043478260869565216]

Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
